# Python. Парс строки после определенного символа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всех приветствую. 
Интересует как в Python 3.8 сделать парс строки после символа @ и до символа ;.
Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Предоставьте пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить из них.

Answer (score 2):

Итак, используя модуль `re` вышел вот такой кусочек кода:

```
import re

raw_string = "Some info....@string_to_be_parced;....info"

result_string = re.search(r'(?<=@)(.*)(?=;)', raw_string)

print(result_string.group())
```

Выводом будет `string_to_be_parced`

К сожалению, Вы не предоставили примеров исходных строк для парсинга, поэтому если возникают вопросы, можете обращаться к официальной документации по модулю `re`: [Тык](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)